# Use i18n in js files

Tags: javascript, internationalization

In `"index.pug"` I include a js file:

```
script
    include ../../public/js/coupon.js
```

In `"coupon.js"` I cannot use `i18n` function:

`#{__('Hello')}`

Have any idea for this?

Comment: please add more code or details

Comment: I found solution. I created a API, js file will use ajax call for translation.